# How to read data in a specific memory address in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have created an integer variable using the following code in *first.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myvar = 10;
    cout << &myvar;

// I only need two steps above.
// The following steps are coded to make this program run continuously.

    cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of first.cpp is:

```
>0x6dfed4
```

While the above program is running, I also run the following program in *second.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // I this program I want to read the content in myvar variable in first.cpp
    // How to do it ?

}
```

Using the second program, I want to read the content of the `myvar` variable in first.cpp.

How to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You generally cannot read memory from one program in another (except via methods that the operating system might offer, in which case it would be important what operating system you are targeting).

Comment: First I would suggest to read upon process isolation and virtual memory.

Comment: Each program will run in a different process. Each process has a separate adddress space. Therefore using the address of a variable in another process is useless. In order to access variables from 2 processes, you can use some kind of shared memory mechanism (usually OS dependent).

Comment: We seem to be looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What you really want to do is send some info from one running program to another. You believe doing that works via pointers/adresses. (It does not.) Please aks about communication between running programs.

Comment: If you want to communicate between different processes, use Inter Process Communication library like zmq, boost, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above:

As I wrote each program will run in a **different process**.
Each process has a **separate adddress space**.
Therefore using the address of a variable in another process doesn't make any sense.

In order to communicate between processes, you need some kind of **IPC** (inter-process communication):
 [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

If you only need to share a variable, the first mechanism that comes to mind is to use **shared memory**:
[Shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)

Shared-memory is very much **OS dependent**.
You didn't mention which OS you are using.
On Windows you can use Win API for managing shared memory:
[Windows shared memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory)

There's an equivalent on Linux, but I am not familiar with the details.

Alternatively you can use the boost solution which is cross platform:
[boost shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html)

If you'll delve into that it will be clear that these kind of solutions comes with **some compilcations**.

**So the question is why do you need to do it ?** Maybe there's a better solution to your problem
(you haven't described what it actually is, so there's not much more I can say).

Comment: No special reason. I am new to c++, So, It was an experiment